# Symfony2: dev to prod, win to unix, clear cache

Tags: windows, unix, symfony, production-environment

I have written a small Symfony2-Webapp. This worked on win in dev and prod. Than I uploaded all files to the provider and run into some issues:

The log-file tells me, that the twig-engine can't find a view. This helped, because a saw, that I had to correct one capital (index instead of Index) - it's always the same developing under windows and having production under unix.

I corrected the file and uploaded it. Than I deleted the cache (no console).

Still, the error resists!

What can I do?

---

New informations:
The problem exists, when not warming up the cache (dev and prod). If using console cache:warmup, than the cache is generated right.
As I found out, the in one generated file, the function 'getTemplateName()' is wrong. All other references in that file are correct.

Sadly, I have no console on my server.

---

EDIT: Answers:

1) Error is: *request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "sisicalBundle:Index:index.html.twig"." at /var/www/web1261/html/sisical/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 133 {"exception":"[object]*

I searched the hole src-folder in eclipse: none of my code uses 'Index' (with capital) any more (since I corrected this). Does symphony create sources in 'vendors...' when installing them via composer?

2) I think I don't use assets and they are not the problem.

3) As logs and cache are written, permissions seem to be OK.

4) Good idea, but I can't find an use. I use templating and for that no 'use'-imports for templates. Seaching for 'Index' I found the wrong template-name generated in the cache. Clearing and warming cache does not help.
Is it possible, that twig generates wrong when using Index as a package/folder name?

Comment: What are the actual errors that are being created?

Comment: Did you installed and dumped the assets?

Comment: did you set writable permissions to cache and log folders?

Comment: You probably changed the filename, but forgot to change the letter in the path to class in your `use` statements

Answer (score 0):

I debugged a little bit:

When warming the cache, the FilesystemLoader parses the file system... > works well. But when running with no cache, the template-engine uses the TemplateGuesser.php which calculates the foldername from the controllername. This one is capital, because it's from a class-name....

I now saw, that I use upper cases in my other project. This time I thought 'always lower cases is the easiest...'.